# Redirect PostgreSQL Qt driver stdout/stderr output

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, qt4.7

I currently call `qInstallMsgHandler()` to redirect all Qt Errors, Warnings, and Debug output to my own message handler.

This works 99% of the time but when executing SQL statements through the QSqlQuery object I still get the following output to stderr:

```
**WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal

LINE 1: EXECUTE qpsqlpstmt_11 ('<?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''U

HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for backslashes, e.g., E'\\'.**
```

The database is PostgresSQL version 8.4. Any ideas how I can also intercept and redirect this warning?

Comment: Isn't that warning generated by the server?

Comment: Looks to me like it comes from the postgres driver. I can't see it anywhere in Qt.

Comment: It comes from here: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c202ecf9023ac3571709c274b326038ae39e90a7/src/backend/parser/scan.l#L1475

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some PostgreSQL library which is being used by the Qt driver writes to `stderr`.

Yan can redicrect `stderr` like this:

```
freopen("my_log.txt", "w", stderr);
```

Comment: Thanks hank. Unfortunately that will also redirect the other messages in my MessageHandler that are currently being output to stderr (qFatal and qCritical messages specifically). I was hoping to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For others with the same issue you can disable the warning with this code:

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.exec("SET standard_conforming_strings TO true");
```

But unfortunately this means the problem is hidden from the caller and the backslashes are escaped automatically in the database which may cause problems when retrieving the data later.